# I'm looking for a book from the 70's or older where a man inherits a computer from his uncle

Tags: books, artificial-intelligence, story-identification

I'm looking for a book from the 70's or older where a man inherits a computer from his uncle. The book involved the main character, his friend, and a woman. Something about artificial intelligence.

Comment: You haven't given the community much to go on. Can you provide any additional details ?  Rough ages of the characters, general plot line, audience type (was this young adult for ex), length (short story, full blown novel), etc..

Comment: What language was the book in; was it translated from another language. What happens in the book and does the computer cause it, or does it help solve it? And you tagged it [ai], so I'm sure there must be more you remember; otherwise you wouldn't have given it that tag...

Comment: @user14111 Point is to change future behavior. Also not the first question to get additional answers after first one has been posted.  Community must have thought there was some benefit since it did get sufficient VTKs.  With that said, kudos to you for coming up with an answer.

Comment: @user14111 Like you said, I was the 5th voter - didn't start the process.  And don't understand your angst.  You did get your answer posted, correct ?  Glad you were able to provide an answer with so little to go on.  Hopefully future questions by Don will provide the community more to go on.

Comment: Is there anything sci-fi/fantasy about the book?

Comment: @RogueJedi If the book is correctly identified in the answer below, it involves artificial intelligence and time travel. In any case, you can see from the edit history that the OP applied the artificial-intelligence tag.

Comment: I've voted to reopen *and* downvoted. The fact that User14111 was able to find a match is a testament to his skill rather than the OP actually being in any way helpful.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7061/looking-for-time-travel-book-set-in-the-60s-or-70s

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156890/looking-for-a-sci-fi-collection-book-2000-to-2010-containing-two-specific-storie (about an anthology containing this story)

Answer (score 13):

[*The Great Time Machine Hoax*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2999)  aka *A Hoax in Time* by [Keith Laumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Laumer). There's a plot summary on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Time_Machine_Hoax).

Let's go over the question point by point.

**I'm looking for a book from the 70's or older**

Laumer's novel *The Great Time Machine Hoax* was first published in hardcover in [1964](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?41032), reissued in paperback in [1965](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?41033), [1974](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?268586), [1978](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?199481), [etc.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?2999). It was based on a magazine serial which appeared, as "A Hoax in Time", in the [June](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58218+c), [July](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58214+c), and [August, 1963](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58202+c) issues of *Fantastic Stories of Imagination*, which are available at the Internet Archive ([[1](https://archive.org/stream/Fantastic_v12n06_1963-06#page/n61/mode/2up)], [[2](https://archive.org/stream/Fantastic_v12n07_1963-07#page/n45/mode/2up)], [[3](https://archive.org/stream/Fantastic_v12n08_1963-08#page/n39/mode/2up)]).

**where a man inherits a computer from his uncle**

Chester W. Chester IV inherits his **great-grandfather's**  mansion, half-filled by a giant computer of his own invention:

> "The old gentleman called it a Generalized Nonlinear Extrapolator. G.N.E. for short. He made his money in computer components, you know. He was fascinated by computers, and he felt they had tremendous unrealized possibilities. Of course, that was before Crmblznski's Limit was discovered. Great-grandfather was convinced that a machine with sufficiently extensive memory banks, adequately cross-connected and supplied with a vast store of data, would be capable of performing prodigious intellectual feats simply by discovering and exploring relationships among apparently unrelated facts."

**The book involved the main character, his friend, and a woman.**

Chester is accompanied on his adventures by his friend Case Mulvihill . . .

> Chester grunted and turned up the collar of his conservatively cut pale lavender sports jacket, thumbing the heat control up to medium. He made his way across the lot, bucking the gusty wind, wrinkling his nose at the heavy animal stink from the menagerie, and squeezed past a plastic panel into the midway. On a low stand under a striped canopy, a broad, tall man with fierce red hair, a gigantic mustache and a checkered suit leaned against a supporting pole, picking his teeth. At sight of Chester, he straightened, flipped up a gold-headed cane and boomed, "You're just in time, friend. Plenty of seating on the inside for the most astounding, amazing, fantastic, weird and startling galaxy of fantasy and—"
> Don't waste the spiel, Case," Chester cut in, coming up. "It's only me."

. . . and a "woman" named Genie:

> There was a faint sound from behind them. Chester turned. A young girl stood on the rug, looking around as if fascinated by the neo-Victorian décor. Glossy dark hair curled about her oval face. She caught Chester's eye and stepped around to stand before him on the rug, a slender, modest figure wearing a golden suntan and a scarlet hair ribbon. Chester gulped audibly. Case dropped his cigar.
> "Perhaps I should have mentioned, Mr. Chester," the computer said, "that the mobile speaker you requested is ready. I carried on the work in an entropic vacuole, permitting myself thereby to produce a complex entity in a very brief period, subjectively speaking."
> Chester gulped again.
> "Hi!" Case said, breaking the stunned silence.
> "Hello," said the girl. Her voice was melodiously soft. She reached up to adjust her hair ribbon, smiling at Case and Chester. "My name is Genie."
> "Uh . . . wouldn't you like to borrow my shirt?"
> "Knock it off, Chester," Case said. You remind me of those characters you see on Tri-D that hide every time they see a pretty girl in the bathtub."
> "I don't think the computer got the idea after all," Chester said weakly.
> "It's pretty literal," Case said. "We only worried about the scenes . . ."
> "I selected this costume as appropriate to the primitive setting," the girl said. "As for my physical characteristics, the intention was to produce the ideal of the average young female, without mammary hypertrophy or other exaggeration, to evoke a sisterly or maternal response in women, while the reaction of male members of the audience should be a fatherly one."
> "I'm not sure it's working on me," said Chester, breathing hard.
> The pretty face looked troubled. "Perhaps the body should be redesigned, Mr. Chester."
> "Don't change a thing," Case said hastily. "And call me Case."
> Chester moved closer to Case. "Funny," he whispered. "She talks just like the computer."
> "What's funny about that? It *is* the computer talking. This is just a robot, remember, Chester."